# Create a dictionary using comprehension with nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a nested for loop in which I am setting the key, value for my new dictionary. Having found out about list comprehensions, I'm wondering if it's possible to use the same logic for a dictionary.

My attempt at one line comprehension for the dictionary which currently fails:

```
dict_contract_name_id = {each_contract: each_contract.id for each_inuring_layer in context.program_obj.inuringLayers for each_contract in each_inuring_layer.contracts}
```

It fails by saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'ContractWithId'`.

Actual code I'm trying to convert to one line comprehension:

```
dict_contract_name_id = {}
for each_inuring_layer in context.program_obj.inuringLayers:
    for each_contract in each_inuring_layer.contracts:
        if each_contract.name in contracts:
            dict_contract_name_id[each_contract.name] = each_contract.id
```

Comment: You forgot the `if`.

Comment: *How* does yours fail? Is there an error?

Comment: Fails by saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'ContractWithId'`

Comment: Right, you also forgot the `.name` attribute.

Comment: `each_contract.name` is different to `each_contract`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `.name` attribute, as well as the `if` filter:

```
dict_contract_name_id = {
    each_contract.name: each_contract.id
    for each_inuring_layer in context.program_obj.inuringLayers
    for each_contract in each_inuring_layer.contracts
    if each_contract.name in contracts}
```

You tried to use the `each_contract` object as a key, and not just the name.